# Oracle ADF: Generating Table from managed Bean

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am developing a web application using Oracle ADF. I have a bounded task flow in  that i have a page fragment in that I have a table. I am generating this table from managed bean. The following is my table

[image]

I have pasted **"#{pageFlowScope.tableUtilBean.tableList}"** in value field of table in the property inspector. My table is successfully generated.

I have a method in a managed bean called generateTable(). The table will be generated after executing a query. Suppose the query result contains 10 records the table will have 10 rows.

My problem is suppose if the query result is having 100 records this method is executing 100 times and the query is executing 100 times. Due to this, It is taking too much time to generate the table. I need to make sure that this method gets executes only once.

Please help me. How do I achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your task flow try to create a Method Activity and make it default activity. This method action should call #{pageFlowScope.tableUtilBean.generateTable}, before fragment is loaded.

Comment: Thanks a lot florinmarcus. This is working for me. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

And when you have a query to show result then why are you populating table from managed bean
just create a ViewObject from SQL Query and drop it on page as af:table

Make use of ADF Business components

Ashish

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. You are exactly correct. But I am accessing this page from multiple pages. Suppose that I have two pages a.jsff and b.jsff. Query is different when I am accessing this fragment from a.jsff and b.jsff. I think if I create a VO then query is fixed. If possible can you tell me how to change VO query before getting this table is loaded. Thanks a lot.